# How to center the view by middle panel in swing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have to build a `UI` with three panels, `leftPanel`, `middlePanel` and `rightPanel`, Panels should be aligned `Horizontally`

`left` and `right` panels should get the `maximum` and `equal` width as possible while the middle panel can get the `minimum` width as its child component required, once the panels are added view should be centered by middle panel.

I have done following test code to build the UI

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SwingTest extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SwingTest() {
        setTitle("Swing Test");
        setSize(750, 350);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());

        // Rule used to find the component positions, for the testing purpose
        Rule rule = new Rule(Rule.HORIZONTAL, true);
        rule.setPreferredWidth(10);
        rule.setPreferredHeight(40);

        SidePanel leftPanel = new SidePanel("Left");
        SidePanel rightPanel = new SidePanel("Right");

        JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();
        middlePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        // Add left,right and middle panel horizontally
        JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel();
        containerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(containerPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        containerPanel.add(leftPanel);
        containerPanel.add(middlePanel);
        containerPanel.add(rightPanel);

        // Add rule and container panel Vertically
        JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
        outerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(outerPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        outerPanel.add(rule);
        outerPanel.add(containerPanel);

        add(outerPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingTest test = new SwingTest();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class SidePanel extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private SidePanel(String text) {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel(text));
        }
    }
}
```

I have used `Rule` class from oracle swing tutorial site, it can be used to find the position of components. get [Rule.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ScrollDemoProject/src/components/Rule.java)

The problem i have is as shown in the UI screen shot, view is not get centered by middle panel, Right now the view centered as width of `left + middle panel = right panel'

I don't want to set the panel height and width manually, It should be handled by the `LayoutManager` itself.

[image]

What i want is middle panel has to be get centered in a way `left + middle/2 = middle/2 + right` panel width.

I couldn't find a way to make the middle panel to get centered to view, Could someone help me to find a solution for this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how the BoxLayout works.

First space is allocated at the preferred size of each component. Then if there is extra space, that space is allocated to each component.

The middle doesn't appear to be centered because the preferred size of the right label is larger than the left label. So when the extra space is allocated the right side is larger than the left side.

This is easy to test. Just change the text of the right side panel to "LEFT".

However, that leads to another question - Why doesn't the size of the middle panel change? I don't know the answer to this. Although for some reason the default FlowLayout seems to work different than the GridBagLayout. Again you can test this by changing the layout of the middle panel to be a GridBagLayout.

If you always want the left/right panels to be the same size then you might want to consider using the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). Using this layout the basic code would be:

```
 RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(RelativeLayout.X_AXIS);
 JPanel panel = new JPanel( rl );
 panel.add(leftPanel, new Float(1));
 panel.add(middle, new Float(3));
 panel.add(rightPanel, new Float(1));
```

Now the left/right panels will be the same size independent of the components added to each panel.